User Behaviour Anomaly Detection
I´m trying to detect anomalies in the behaviour of users in an app. My dataset have several fields, but I think the most important ones are User Id, TimeStamp, and Event_name.
So for example I could have something like this:
User Id   TimeStamp   Event_name
User_1    00000001    login_google
User_1    00000451    friend_request
User_2    00000012    login_apple
And so on... I´m trying to find the best way to encode the event_name fields, because there are a little more than 100 events so I d´ont think onehotencoder is appropiate.
The approach I´m taking  is to use LSTM to model sequence relationship between events and then feed those vector into another model like Clustering or Isolation Forest. Could anyone guide me about encoding and if the approach I´m taking is valid?
Thanks in advance.
